# C# WPF Livecharts Formatter

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I have hit somewhat of a roadblock with livecharts and formatting my x axis. I have to accommodate for a few different options. I am importing data that can range from 10 seconds to over 2 hours worth of data points. when using

```
    Formatter = value => new DateTime((long)(value * 
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).Ticks)).ToString("mm:ss");
```

I get [restarting values at every hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN3Hu.png)

but when using

```
   Formatter = value => new DateTime((long)(value * TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).Ticks)).ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

I get [values starting at 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WSMV.png)

How do I get better formatted times starting at 0:00:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another `TimeSpan.FromHours(12)` - basically moving the time forward 12 hours.